# VBA DOM Find Specific Nodes With Attributes

Tags: xml, vba, dom, xml-parsing, attributes

I have a large XML file that I'm trying to parse using DOM. What I'm trying to do is only pull information from a node if it's parent contains a specific "id" attribute.

For example, if I only want to pull the TITLE or AUTHOR for books containing "id = Adventure" - how would I do it using DOM?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<book id="Adventure">
   <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
   <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   <price>44.95</price>
</book>
<book id="Adventure">
   <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
   <title>Midnight Rain</title>
   <price>5.95</price>
</book>
<book id="Adventure">
   <author>Boal, John</author>
   <title>Mist</title>
   <price>15.95</price>
</book>
<book id="Mystery">
   <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
   <title>Some Mystery Book</title>
   <price>9.95</price>
</book>
</catalog>
```

Now using this code:

```
Sub mySub()

Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Dim XCMFILE As Variant
Dim BookType As String
Dim BookTitle As Variant
Dim Title As String
Dim n As IXMLDOMNode
Dim i As Integer

Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set XCMFILE = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

XCMFILE.Load (XCMFileName) 'Load XCM File


i = 0

For Each n In XCMFILE.SelectNodes("/catalog/book")
    BookType= n.Attributes.getNamedItem("id").Text 'Search for id attribute within node
    If BookID = "Adventure" Then
        Set BookTitle = = XCMFILE.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/title/text()")
        Title = BookTitle(i).NodeValue
        mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i + 3).Value = BookTitle'Prints values into B column
        i = i + 1
    EndIf

Next
End Sub
```

I don't know how to increment properly to only pull the nodes that fit my specification/category.

Thanks for any tips and pointers - I appreciate it.

Comment: The XPath in `XCMFILE.SelectNodes("/catalog/book")` should be able to only select the `id=Adventure` nodes, so they would be the only nodes you need to iterate

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by XPath. Are you saying that since Adventure is the first type that appears, it would only go to that?

Comment: The string you put there is called an XPath; there's a way to make it only return the nodes you're interested in, lookup "xpath select nodes with specific attribute value" ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mat. One quick question though, I keep getting an error "Compile Error: Expected: list separator or )" Any idea what this means? My line of code reads BookTitle.SelectNodes("/catalog/book[@id="bk102"/author/text()")... the error actually highlights "bk102"

Comment: Hard to tell, but if your string has quotes, they need to be doubled-up /escaped.

Comment: Sorry Mat, can you explain that to me as if I were an 8 year old? So if the line is (book id="Adventure") my string would have to be ("/catalog/book[@id=""bk102""] or quotes around the entire ("@id="bk102"")?

Comment: You need a set of quotes to tell VBA "hey look, that's a literal string", and then since that string literal needs to contain quotes, you need to put 2 for each one so that VBA won't think "oh hey, so your string literal ends here right?" and go boom when it finds that the next character is also a double-quote ;) so `"""hello, world"""` outputs `"hello, world"`

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `chr(34)` function. `chr(34) & "hello, world" & chr(34)` also outputs `"hello, world"`.

Comment: In other words, you need `"/catalog/book[@id=""bk102""]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to increment anything. Just write an XPath query that selects only the nodes you're interested in:

```
For Each n In XCMFILE.SelectNodes("/catalog/book[@id=""Adventure""]")
    ' n is a book node with the "id" attribute value "Adventure"
Next
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. I had to use single quotes for 'Adventure' without an error being thrown. Appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple attribute conditions? `For Each n In XCMFILE.SelectNodes("/catalog/book[@id=""Adventure""]" & @version="1.0")`

Comment: Got it (I think), `For Each n In XCMFILE.SelectNodes("/catalog/book[@id=""Adventure"" and @version=""& myVar &""]")`